# Drag and dropping with visual indication

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, javafx, line, draggable

I am trying to implement a drag and drop between 2 objects.

The problem is when I drag from one rectangle to the other I need the start of a line to be connected on the source rectangle and the end of the line to follow the mouse around.

Then when I drop at the second rectangle the end of the line should bind at it and a string passed.

On one hand using onmouseclicked, dragged, and released I managed to make the line follow the mouse around but am not able to make the second rectangle understand that the mouse was released on it (as shown in the code below)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test extends Application {
double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new BorderPane();

    Rectangle rect1=new Rectangle(100,50);
    rect1.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Label rect1_label=new Label("Rectangle 1");
    rect1_label.setLayoutX(20);rect1_label.setLayoutY(15);
    rect1.setLayoutX(220);rect1.setLayoutY(240);

    Line line=new Line (rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth(),rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2,
                        rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth(),rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2);
    line.startXProperty().bind(rect1.translateXProperty().add(rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth()));
    line.startYProperty().bind(rect1.translateYProperty().add(rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2));
    line.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(10.0, 5.0);

    Rectangle rect2=new Rectangle(100,50);
    rect2.setFill(Color.BISQUE);rect2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Label rect2_label=new Label("Rectangle 2");
    rect2_label.setLayoutX(20);rect2_label.setLayoutY(15);
    rect2.setLayoutX(600);rect2.setLayoutY(240);


    root.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,line);


        rect1.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            public void handle(MouseEvent event){
                line.setVisible(true);
                line.toBack();
                line.setEndX(event.getX());
                line.setEndY(event.getY());
                orgSceneX = event.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = event.getSceneY();
                orgTranslateX = ((Rectangle)(event.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                orgTranslateY = ((Rectangle)(event.getSource())).getTranslateY();
                line.setEndX(event.getSceneX());
                line.setEndY(event.getSceneY());
            }
        });

        rect1.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                double offsetX = event.getSceneX();
                double offsetY = event.getSceneY();
                double newTranslateX = offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = offsetY;
                line.setEndX(newTranslateX);
                line.setEndY(newTranslateY);
            }
        });

        rect1.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                line.setVisible(false);
            }
        });



    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Nodes test 1");
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(1000);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

.

I also know how to drag and drop a value or string from one object to another like that

.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test2 extends Application {
double orgSceneX, orgSceneY;
double orgTranslateX, orgTranslateY;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane root = new BorderPane();

    Rectangle rect1=new Rectangle(100,50);
    rect1.setFill(Color.AQUAMARINE);rect1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Label rect1_label=new Label("Rectangle 1");
    rect1_label.setLayoutX(20);rect1_label.setLayoutY(15);
    rect1.setLayoutX(220);rect1.setLayoutY(240);

    Line line=new Line (rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth(),rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2,
                        rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth(),rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2);
    line.startXProperty().bind(rect1.translateXProperty().add(rect1.getLayoutX()+rect1.getWidth()));
    line.startYProperty().bind(rect1.translateYProperty().add(rect1.getLayoutY()+rect1.getHeight()/2));
    line.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(10.0, 5.0);

    Rectangle rect2=new Rectangle(100,50);
    rect2.setFill(Color.BISQUE);rect2.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Label rect2_label=new Label("Rectangle 2");
    rect2_label.setLayoutX(20);rect2_label.setLayoutY(15);
    rect2.setLayoutX(600);rect2.setLayoutY(240);


    root.getChildren().addAll(rect1,rect2,line);

    rect1.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event){
            Dragboard db = rect1.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString("rec");
            db.setContent(content);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    rect2.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
        public void handle(DragEvent event) {
            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            event.consume();
        }
    });

    rect2.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>(){
        @Override public void handle(DragEvent event){
            final Dragboard db = event.getDragboard(); 
            if (db.getString().equals("rec")){
                System.out.println("Accepted");
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Nodes test 1");
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(1000);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```

If I use them both something goes wrong

What can I do in order for the line to be drawn and the value to be passed at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activate a "full press-drag-release gesture" by calling `startFullDrag` on the node where the drag originated. The differences between the types of drag gesture are detailed in the [Javadocs for `MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html), but basically this allows mouse events to be delivered to nodes other than the node that originated the drag while the drag is in process.

Note, though, that you don't get a `mouseReleased` event on a node unless the mouse was pressed on that node (as far as I can tell). So you need to do a little bit of work to figure out if the release occurred over the second rectangle. I did this by setting a flag if the mouse entered the node during the drag and set it to false if it exits. You could also probably do this by looking for a mouse release on the underlying container, and seeing if the bounds of the node included the coordinates of the mouse event.

Also note in this example that I needed to call `line.setMouseTransparent(true);` to make sure the line didn't consume the mouse events.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DragAndDropWithLine extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(50, 50, 50, 100);
        rect1.setFill(Color.YELLOW);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(200, 50, 50, 100);
        rect2.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        Line line = new Line();
        line.setMouseTransparent(true);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(rect1, rect2);

        BooleanProperty dragging = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        BooleanProperty draggingOverRect2 = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

        rect1.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            rect1.startFullDrag();
            Point2D mouseSceneCoords = new Point2D(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
            Point2D mousePaneCoords = pane.sceneToLocal(mouseSceneCoords);
            line.setStartX(mousePaneCoords.getX());
            line.setStartY(mousePaneCoords.getY());
            line.setEndX(mousePaneCoords.getX());
            line.setEndY(mousePaneCoords.getY());
            pane.getChildren().add(line);
            dragging.set(true);
        });

        pane.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            if (dragging.get()) {
                line.setEndX(event.getX());
                line.setEndY(event.getY());
            }
        });

        rect1.setOnMouseReleased(event -> {
            if (draggingOverRect2.get()) {
                pane.getChildren().remove(rect1);
                rect2.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            }
            dragging.set(false);
            draggingOverRect2.set(false);
            pane.getChildren().remove(line);
        });

        rect2.setOnMouseDragEntered(event -> {
            if (dragging.get()) {
                draggingOverRect2.set(true);
            }
        });

        rect2.setOnMouseDragExited(event -> draggingOverRect2.set(false));


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You set me on the right track and made it work as intended. Guess it helps studying the docs a bit closer :-)